# scan error : the value of local variable scan is not used

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KillBill {

    public KillBill() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    }

}
```

IN 11th LINE .IT SAYS THE VALUE OF LOCAL VARIABLE SCAN IS NOT USED

Comment: Do you use the variable scan anywhere?

Comment: `variable not used` - should be a warning by IDE

Comment: complete your program please and then look for warnings... not in the middle

Comment: Also, when choosing a variable name, in your example it's `Scan` as in `Scanner Scan`. Please stick to the camelCase naming convention: `Scanner scan` or `Scanner myScanner`

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is set and not used, it gives an error. You could correct the warning by using Scan, with something like:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String text = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

The idea here is that every variable is being used now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class KillBill {

    public KillBill(Scanner scan) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        int value = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        new KillBill(Scan);
    }
}
```

That problem/warning is caused by unused variable. Not a serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be entirely honest, you're Scanner object ISN'T BEING USED elsewhere in the code you've provided. But don't worry, this is just a warning (yellow jagged underline) and not an error (red jagged underline). In this case, it's just telling you that your program, at the moment, has an unused variable, whose deletion won't affect the code than what it currently is. Remember, a computer still has to read each line, and reading unused variables, especially objects, might slow your program down, even though by only a fraction of a millisecond. So it is advised to delete this unnecessary lines of code.

But remember, this is all relevant for the CURRENT situation, and not if you're gonna make changes to your program, by literally USING your unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem to declare Scanner and not use it, the real problem is the signature of your main method signature, it should not UpperCase you have to use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//                  ^^-----------------In your program it is M
```

**Note** java use CamelCase your names of variables shold start with lower case for the good practice (Scan should be scan)